# unable to mock capacitor plugins in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, jasmine, capacitor

my tsconfig.spec.json

```
"paths": {
   "@test/*": ["tests/*"],
   "@capacitor/*": ["tests/src/mocks/capacitor/*"]
}
```

I have a Camera.ts file located under **tests/src/mocks/capacitor/camera.ts** which implements the CameraPlugin from Capacitor.

still, when doing any tests i receive the "not implemented on web"

```
  An error was thrown in afterAll
  Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Not implemented on web.
  error properties: Object({ code: 'UNIMPLEMENTED' })
```

somebody know what i am missing?
Appreciate!

Answer (score 1):

Have you declared "paths" in the correct place? It should be set inside "compilerOptions"

here's an example tsconfig.spec.json file.

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/spec",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "node"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@capacitor/*": ["__mocks__/@capacitor/*"],
      "@capacitor-community/*":["__mocks__/@capacitor-community/*"]
    }
  },
  "files": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```